# Permission denied using Supervisor

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm running django on Ubuntu with gunicorn and nginx. I'm also using jenkins to build. Gunicorn for serving the django and nginx for static file. Gunicorn will running as a background service. Herefore I'm using supervisord. Now I want to post an image into my database, using my backend. But I get this error (the bmp is my image):

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/crwll8z4.bmp'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://url:9000/post/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     OSError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/crwll8z4.bmp'
Exception Location:     /.virtualenvs/newenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in _save, line 219
```

After doing some research I learned that's it important which instance let run your backend. So it's my supervisord who runs my backend. But my supervisord is started as root. And a root will be able to write down every file (also my image) in every directory. When I'm doing htop I don't see an instance of gunicorn. Only the one of supervisord. So I'm really stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with supervisor. Rather, it's with your media settings; you're trying to save the file in the root directory, which is not allowed.

Comment: How do you mean? I think it's trying to save the file in my jenkins workspace were my project takes place. And the database will refer to that picture or am I wrong?

Comment: No, I think it is trying to save it in `/`. Please show your MEDIA_* settings.

Comment: Yep you were right! Had to change my MEDIA in settings.py to the right folder and give the right permissions.